# Understanding basic git hooks

Tags: git, bash

I'm new to both git and unix so please bear with. I'm trying to create a simple git post-receive hook in a repository I've setup on ec2.  In the hooks folder, I have a file named post-receive that attempts to update a public site's working directory.

```
#!/bin/sh

echo 'hi git'
cd /home/www-data/web2py/applications/init
sudo git checkout .
sudo git pull
echo 'done'
```

But after a push, nothing seems to happen. The site's working directory does not get updated and when I run git log there are no signs of errors or my echo statements. I guess I'm missing something? Thanks.

Comment: I think you want `git fetch` instead of `git pull`, since pull tries to merge the incoming head with a newer local head, while fetch only get the new changes.

Comment: @Rudi Could you expand on this, perhaps with some examples? I've been using git pull and it seems to be working the way I want it to--we push our changes and the public site is automatically updated--but I still haven't used either git fetch or git branches in any form, so I don't have a good understanding of the issues involved. I'm part of a two-person team and we are basically using git like branchless-svn-with-hooks so far and have been happy with this workflow, but I'm very open to and interested in taking better advantage of git, but I still don't really grok the vocabulary. Thanks.

Comment: git pull tries to merge the local changes with the new incoming stuff. As long as no one places commits in the webside folder, this is no problem. But when someone commits stuff there, then the next pull will try to merge the incoming changes with the local commit. When this merge fails because of conflicts, then the folder is left in a state with conflict markers in every conflicted file, which is probably not what you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First: git log is not the log of the git binary. :) It is used to see the commits and their revisions.

Do you see the "hi git" and "done" output somewhere? My guess is that your hook is not executable. Run `chmod +x your_hook` - This will make it executable.